# Custom fonts are shown in inspector, but the font isn't changing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, asset-pipeline

I have been trying to get these custom fonts working. The server starts up like normal, nothing strange shows up in the console log, it shows in the inspector that they are taking the font-family: "audimatregular" but the font isn't changing.

home.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'audimatregular';
  src:url('audimatregular.otf');
  src:url('audimat.eot?#iefix') format('otf'),
    url('audimatbold.svg#audimat') format('otf'),
    url('audimatbolditalic.woff') format('otf'),
    url('audimatitalic.ttf') format('otf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.section1 {
  font-family: "audimatregular";
}
```

Folder tree

```
/app
+---assets
|   +---fonts
|   |       audimatbolditalic.otf
|   |       audimatitalic.otf
|   |       audimatbold.otf
|   |       audimatregular.otf
|   +---images
|   +---javascripts
|   +---stylesheets
```

rails version

```
Rails 5.1.3
```

Server logs

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-21 21:13:09 -0400
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
  Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (781.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 879ms (Views: 869.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: How are they "not working"? what specific other answers and tutorials have you looked at, so that we don't repeat anything you've already tried? What else have you tried?

Comment: They just flat our aren't working, the server starts up like normal, nothing strange shows up in the console log, it shows in the inspector that they are taking the font-family: "audimatregular" but the font isn't changing.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the font-url helper to your css:

```
src:font-url('...')
```

Here is my code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'audimatregular';
  src:font-url('AUdimat-Regular.otf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Make sure you restart your server after making the changes.

Comment: I think you need to direct to the fonts path. src:url('fonts/audimatregular.otf'); etc.

Comment: Make sure your src:font-url is specified exactly as the font name. I had to do this to make it work:
```src:font-url('AUdimat-Regular.otf');```

Comment: hashrocket could I get all of the code you used? because I just did that and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use to do:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; 
src: url('/assets/segoe.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/assets/segoe.woff') format('woff'), 
url('/assets/segoe.woff2') format('woff2'), 
url('/assets/segoe.ttf')  format('truetype'), url('/assets/segoe.svg#svgSegoe') format('svg');}
```

No matter *where* in Assets you put things, you can always just use `/assets/asset.jpg` to link to that specific file, cause the pipeline will look through all folders under `/assets`. – But if you add a custom folder, like **`assets/fonts`**, **you must add that folder to the pipeline**, see [this question](http://require) on how to do that.  If you feel that is too complicated, just put all the font files in the images-folder (or any **existing** folder within the assets folder)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you used scaffolds? If you have scaffolds.css.scss anywhere that will block custom fonts.

Also, have you checked the rails server logs when you load a page that should have the font? What error is it giving?

Comment: No I'm not using scaffolds and I just posted the logs in the original post

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I am quite interested to know what the issue was if you have done so.

Comment: I havent quite yet, I had to move on to different things but once I do figure it out ill post it here

Comment: Thanks, I like to make notes in Quiver for things like this so I can tag them in case I ever encounter in the future so I appreciate it (sorry I can't solve it though!)